# How to make this custom RangeSlider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-web

I want to make a custom Range slider that looks like this:

### [image: Expected result]

However, I tried but my RangeSlider looks like:

### [image]

My code:

```
                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        trackShape: RectangularSliderTrackShape(),
                        trackHeight: 2.0,
                        thumbShape:
                            RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 9.0),
                        overlayShape:
                            RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 18.0),
                        valueIndicatorShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(),
                        valueIndicatorColor: Color(0xffF5F5F5),
                        valueIndicatorTextStyle:
                            TextStyle(color: Color(0xff7E3338), fontSize: 14.0),
                        rangeThumbShape: RoundRangeSliderThumbShape(),
                        rangeValueIndicatorShape:
                            PaddleRangeSliderValueIndicatorShape(),
                      ),
                      child: RangeSlider(
                        values: selectedRange,
                        min: 0.0,
                        max: 50000.0,
                        semanticFormatterCallback: (RangeValues rangeValues) {
                          return '${rangeValues.start.round()} - ${rangeValues.end.round()} dollars';
                        },
                        //added talk back feature for android
                        labels: RangeLabels(
                            '${selectedRange.start}', '${selectedRange.end}'),
                        activeColor: Color(0xff7E3338),
                        inactiveColor: Color(0xffD7D8DD),
                        onChanged: (RangeValues newRange) {
                          setState(() => selectedRange = newRange);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

What can I do different in the code that will give me the expected output?

Answer (score 4):

Please check this plugin where you can customize the slider as you want i have created the sample from the above-mentioned image.
But you can customize it as per your needs.

Plugin :https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider

Check the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_xlider/flutter_xlider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        //
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _lowerValue = 50;
  double _upperValue = 180;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: FlutterSlider(
                  values: [1000, 15000],
                  rangeSlider: true,

//rtl: true,
                  ignoreSteps: [
                    FlutterSliderIgnoreSteps(from: 8000, to: 12000),
                    FlutterSliderIgnoreSteps(from: 18000, to: 22000),
                  ],
                  max: 25000,
                  min: 0,
                  step: FlutterSliderStep(step: 100),

                  jump: true,

                  trackBar: FlutterSliderTrackBar(
                    activeTrackBarHeight: 2,
                    activeTrackBar: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.brown),
                  ),
                  tooltip: FlutterSliderTooltip(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.lightBlue),
                  ),
                  handler: FlutterSliderHandler(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.brown,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  rightHandler: FlutterSliderHandler(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.brown,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  disabled: false,

                  onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
                    _lowerValue = lowerValue;
                    _upperValue = upperValue;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the image output

[image]
you can change the colors accordingly.

Let me know if it works.

Check out this code for tooltip:

```
tooltip: FlutterSliderTooltip(
                    disableAnimation: true,
                    alwaysShowTooltip: true,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.lightBlue),
                  ),
```

Comment: Sir thanks for the effort! However,  what should I do for the label?

Comment: What about the labels can you explain.

Comment: Above each tracker will the number also be displayed?

Comment: check out the edit i have made added the code at last . There it has a parameter called always showtooltip it should be  true and disable animation to true

Comment: Sir I tried the code but the sliders keep snapping.

Comment: what do you mean by snapping. please explain

Comment: can you add some code so that I can tell you where its going wrong.

Comment: By snapping I meant as in when I run the code, on moving the slider it doesn't, it snaps back to its original position

Comment: That's great it worked. Maybe it was because of some value definitions and not reflecting on the ui

Comment: If its right please make a checkmark so that it would be helpful for others if they have any problem.

Comment: Is there any alternative that supports null-safety?

Comment: check this out one of the guy has updated it to null safety :https://github.com/Ali-Azmoud/flutter_xlider/issues/125

Comment: maybe this plugin might get the null saftey update, till then you can use the above one

Comment: @SagarAcharya yes I found it thank you though, it's an awesome package actually

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your Range Slider in Slider theme and customize your slider data theme according to your need. use the bellow image for reference and name of all the properties of slider.
[image]

Comment: Apperently, this is the source: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c